# Error with Symfony Flex: You have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)

Tags: php, symfony, sass, composer-php, symfony-flex

When I run the command `composer install` or `composer update` it shows me the following

```
The following exception probably indicates you have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)
                                                                                                                
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                         
  curl error 6 while downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json: Could not resolve host: flex.symfony.com`
```

I changed DNS but that did not fix the problem.

PHP version : 8.0.0.
I test with php version 7.4

Comment: That site does not exist.  I tried different DNS resolvers (mine, provider, online) and none can find its address.  Something is not properly configured somewhere.

Comment: See https://symfony.com/blog/the-old-flex-infrastructure-is-shutting-down

Answer (score 45):

Old Flex infrastructure is being shut down, you need to update Flex to AT LEAST 1.17.1. To do that, you need to run:

```bash
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

source: https://symfony.com/blog/upgrade-flex-on-your-symfony-projects

Comment: I tryed and that helped me in two projects, thanks.

Comment: This should be marked as answer, it also helped me in my SF project