# curl error 6 while downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json: Could not resolve host: flex.symfony.com

Tags: php, symfony

I am using `symfony4.4`

```
$composer update

curl error 6 while downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json: Could not resolve host: flex.symfony.com
```

There appeared error and I googled around and found this article.

[Error with Symfony Flex: You have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234885/error-with-symfony-flex-you-have-misconfigured-dns-resolvers)

I tried this,

```
$composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

However error again.

```
Cannot update only a partial set of packages without a lock file present. Run `composer update` to generate a lock file.
```

I need to do composer update to generate lock file but composer update shows the error.

It's eternal loop.....

Could you help some hint??

my composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "8.*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.1",
        "msgphp/user-bundle": "0.15.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.*",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "3.*",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.*",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/finder": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2.2.3",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.8",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^2.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/serializer": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/translation": "*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/validator": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `host flex.symfony.com` => `Host flex.symfony.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski What does it mean??

Comment: I posted the answer. I also reopened your question as it was not a duplicate it was linked to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with Symfony Flex: You have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234885/error-with-symfony-flex-you-have-misconfigured-dns-resolvers)

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing you can fix right now because

```bash
$ host flex.symfony.com
Host flex.symfony.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

which simply means there's no such host as flex.symfony.com known to DNS. It might be **their** delegation problem or anything like that but this is not what you are able to fix.

In future you can always use services like https://isitdownrightnow.com to see if this is your local DNS issue or affects everyone:

[image]

Comment: Root cause: https://symfony.com/blog/the-old-flex-infrastructure-is-shutting-down