# laminas/laminas-code 4.3.0 requires php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 using symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony `v5.x` project.

I want to install it on my Windows PC.

I copied the project folder to `wamp/www`.

I execute the command `composer install`.

It throws the following error:

> curl error 6 while downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json: Couldn't resolve host name

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234885/error-with-symfony-flex-you-have-misconfigured-dns-resolvers).
The proposed solution is to execute the command:

```
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

It now throws another error:

```
laminas/laminas-code 4.3.0 requires php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (7.3.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/proxy-manager-bridge v5.3.0 requires friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts ^1.0.2 -> satisfiable by friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts[v1.0.5].
    - friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts v1.0.5 requires laminas/laminas-code ~3.4.1|^4.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-code[4.3.0].
    - symfony/proxy-manager-bridge is locked to version v5.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested
```

I found a possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454412/error-root-composer-json-requires-php-7-3-but-your-php-version-8-0-0-does-no) which proposes to modify `composer.json` as follows:

```
"require": {
  "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
}
```

If I run:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer update symfony/flex \
  --no-plugins \
  --no-scripts
```

... I still get the following error:

> - laminas/laminas-code 4.3.0 requires php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (7.3.5) does not satisfy that requirement` stays.

This is my **composer.json:**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.9",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/asset": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/form": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/google-mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/process": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^2.0",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/string": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/translation": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/validator": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.3.*",
        "tattali/calendar-bundle": "^1.2",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.3",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.3",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "requirements-checker": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your php version?

Comment: thx for u answer but I'm afraid for other projects he won't work

Comment: you can have multiple php versions, just switch between projects :)

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP version `7.3.5` does not satisfy the requirements of `laminas/laminas-code`.

Update the PHP version on your system to `7.4` or `8.0` to resolve the composer error.

Alternatively you can "fake" the current PHP version in `composer.json`.

Use `config.platform` to override the PHP version detected by composer:

```
{
  "config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.4.0"
    }
  }
}
```