# Error with composer update and the download of a version.json file

Tags: symfony, composer-php

While running the composer update command on a symfony project, it fails. The error is the next :

```
The "https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Comment: As you can see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234885/error-with-symfony-flex-you-have-misconfigured-dns-resolvers, this is expected behaviour as the server was shut down. What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Does this answer your question? [Error with Symfony Flex: You have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234885/error-with-symfony-flex-you-have-misconfigured-dns-resolvers) If it doesn't answer your question, provide us your composer.json file. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I think you find the right thing to resolve my problem. But in order to resolve it I have to upgrade php version of the project because it requires a new version of the alice-bundle package :)
I'll do it and keep you informed